# FileExistsError when trying to copy files with makedirs python 3

Tags: python-3.x, mkdir

So I am running this code which takes files from a folder and copies them into another directory. However I get a FileExistsError when i try to make the new directory tree even though I don't create that directory tree anywhere else in the code. What can be wrong?

```
import os
import shutil
import datetime

class CopyFilesModuleTest:

    def __init__(self):
        self.folderName = ""
        self.timeName = CopyFilesModuleTest.formatTimeStr(datetime.datetime.now())

    def getDirFiles(self):
        src_files = os.listdir(self.folderName)
        return src_files

    def copyFiles(self,src_files):
        for file_name in src_files:
            full_file_name = self.folderName+"/"+file_name
            if(os.path.isfile(full_file_name)):
                destPath = self.getNewFileDest(file_name)
                destDir = self.getNewFileDir()
                self.createDirectory(destDir)
                shutil.copy(full_file_name,destPath)

    def getNewFileDest(self,fileName):
        mainFold = "userDataBackUp"
        full_File_Path = mainFold+"/"+self.timeName+"/"+self.folderName+"/"+fileName
        return full_File_Path

    def getNewFileDir(self):
        mainFold = "userDataBackUp"
        full_File_Dir = mainFold+"/"+self.timeName+"/"+self.folderName
        return full_File_Dir

    @staticmethod
    def formatTimeStr(tStr):
        tStr = str(tStr)
        colon = ":"
        space = " "
        dot = "."
        bLine = "-"
        tStr = tStr.replace(colon,"_")
        tStr = tStr.replace(space,"_")
        tStr = tStr.replace(dot,"_")
        tStr = tStr.replace(bLine,"_")
        return tStr

    def createDirectory(self,filePath):
        os.makedirs(filePath)

    def copyAllFromFolder(self,fName):
        self.folderName = fName
        src_files1 = cfm1.getDirFiles()
        cfm1.copyFiles(src_files1)



cfm1 = CopyFilesModuleTest()
cfm1.copyAllFromFolder("folder_files")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the directory probably already exists. `os.makedirs` will raise a `FileExistsError` in this case (that's what my python 3.5 interpreter does; the 3.6 doc says it will raise an `OSError`). this should to the trick:

```
os.makedirs(filePath, exist_ok=True)
```

(as in the doc of [`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=makedirs#os.makedirs)).

Comment: Yep true, my stupid mistake actually, i run the for loop for every file so i try to create the directory again for every file...